# Accessing custom GET-variables in Oracle APEX

Tags: get, oracle-apex, apex

I have an application that sends users to a non-APEX webshop. After they are finished they are sent back to our APEX application along with custom (non-APEX) GET-variables in the URL.

The simplified URL looks like this:

`f?p=101:111&orderID=12345678&currency=EUR`

How can I get the value of the parameters `orderID` and `currency` in APEX without using Javascript?

I am using APEX 23.2.1.

---

I have tried using `:APP_URL` and `APEX_APPLICATION.G_X01` but they both show no data.

`APEX_PAGE.GET_URL` only shows the APEX-part of the URL and not the custom GET-parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the url that is called back you could assign the value of the added string to a page item in APEX and then access that page item in your page. Check the url syntax [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.1/htmdb/understanding-legacy-url-syntax.html#GUID-F249FDCA-972B-4DFB-A51B-DD127AAB9C35).

Example: Consider a page with a page item `P111_ITEM`, set the page attribute "page access protection" to "unrestricted" and enabled deep linking.

The following url `https://<host>/f?p=100:111:::::P111_ITEM:orderID=12345678` will open page 111 in which page item P111_ITEM is assigned value "orderID=12345678". The item value can be parsed in a pre-rendering computation or page process. Note that the number of colons needs to match exactly since it is the argument separator in the url.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I do not have control over the url that is called back.

I did test what you said and it works the way you predicted, although only for one value. If there are more parameters it only processes the first one (I expect because of the & in the url). I have updated my question with a more complete URL example.

Comment: Not sure if that is at all possible and if it is... I don't know how.

Comment: That's too bad to hear. But thank you nonetheless for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Try with OWA_UTIL.get_cgi_env to get the query string with the parameters as string in a Before Header Process
Then split and do what you need
[See here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-http-headers-and-ords-specific-bind-variables)